# dask bokeh port not reused

Tags: bokeh, dask

I'm running some extended tests under dask. I create a LocalCluster and a Client from it, do some processing and then shutdown the Client and close the LocalCluster. On the first test, port 8787 is used for bokeh as expected. However on subsequent tests, the port number is not 8787 but instead some random number. Here's a script that illustrates the problem:

```
from distributed import Client
import time

if __name__ == '__main__':

    max_n_workers = 8
    print('Maximum number of workers is ', max_n_workers)

    n_workers = max_n_workers
    while n_workers > 1:
        c = Client(n_workers=n_workers)
        print(c)
        addr = c.scheduler_info()['address']
        services = c.scheduler_info()['services']
        if 'bokeh' in services.keys():
            bokeh_addr = 'http:%s:%s' % (addr.split(':')[1], services['bokeh'])
            print('Diagnostic pages available on port %s' % bokeh_addr)

        c.shutdown()

        n_workers = n_workers // 2
        time.sleep(10)

exit()
```

And an example output is

```
Maximum number of workers is  8
<Client: scheduler='tcp://127.0.0.1:41049' processes=8 cores=16>
Diagnostic pages available on port http://127.0.0.1:8787
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
<Client: scheduler='tcp://127.0.0.1:34152' processes=4 cores=16>
Diagnostic pages available on port http://127.0.0.1:39621
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
<Client: scheduler='tcp://127.0.0.1:37583' processes=2 cores=16>
Diagnostic pages available on port http://127.0.0.1:45183
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
distributed.nanny - INFO - Worker closed
```

Answer (score 0):

When you close the LocalCluster it shuts down all services.  This gives back all previously used ports to the operating system.  When you start up a new LocalCluster it asks the operating system for these ports again.  If the bokeh port is not yet accessible then it will choose a new random port rather than fail.

In your case I suspect that the operating system has not yet registered the default port as being open.  I suspect that if you gave the operating system some time that things would clear up.

Comment: Hi Matt, I've tried up to 600s with no luck. Is it possible to set a timeout at the time of allocation of the port? Overall I can live with this behaviour so I won't want to ask for any fundamental changes.

Comment: The OS should definitely cycle things within 600s.  There is no internal timeout that is accessible.  I suspect that something else is going on.  I've tried the example that you've given above and get the port at 8787 all 10 times without a timeout.

Comment: OK, I'll try some more experiments.

Comment: Matt, the example is now actual code that I've run. Tim